# Core Bluetooth, Background Execution, Termination and Data Persistence

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, background-process, core-bluetooth

Bit of a mouthful, I know.

I'm working on an app that receives data from a bluetooth peripheral at regular intervals. After, say 20 updates, I persist the data using Core Data, which is more efficient than persisting after every update.

If I've got 10 updates and the user presses home , the app moves to the background, I save the context to persistent storage in the "applicationDidEnterBackground" method - no problem, the 10 updates are saved, even if the app is subsequently terminated.

I've added the UIBackground : bluetooth-central mode so that updates may continue in the background after the user presses the home button. To quote Apple:

> When your app declares this, the system wakes it up from a suspended
>   state to allow it to handle Bluetooth-related events.

So, when a bluetooth update is received, the app moves to the background state, calls the callback (e.g. didUpdateValueForCharacteristic) and then can transition back to the suspended state and may be terminated. All the while, none of the app delegate callbacks are called and the new data is lost.

My question is - how/at what point in this scenario are we to save the new data (or more generally any resulting application state) to persistent storage?

Comment: Is there really a problem with saving after each update? Or is there "premature optimization" type thinking going on? Because saving after each update would be the obvious solution.

Comment: I guess I'm not that concerned about the ble data, so much as the resulting application state. If a ble update causes a change in application state and then the app is killed, I need a way to restore my application state. I could persist the application state after every ble update, but it would be fantastic if that responsibility could be delegated to one central spot in code.. much like the willEncodeRestorableStateWithCoder callback